# WP_User_Query unable to retreive all user at once

Tags: wordpress

I have more than 3000 users with role 'subscriber', and now i want to fetch all users with role 'subscriber'.

My code:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' ) );
$users = $user_query->get_results();

foreach( $users as $user)
{
     // getting user data
}
```

Now when i tried with above code, then my page is not working, it gives me 500 HTTP ERROR saying that

> unable to handle request

So what i need to change in my code so that it gives me all users at once.

In addition to this, same issue happens with `WP_Query()` where we have more than 100 000 posts and we want to show all post on a specific page, so at that time also my server goes down and give me HTTP error 500.

Comment: Could be a PHP timeout issue, check your debug.log file for errors.  Try increasing the maximum execution time ( max_execution_time ) in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't have the right to comment so i have to add it as an answer.

Did you tried to set a number for the users that will be displayed? like this:

```
 $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber', 'number' => 200));
```

Try this at first to find out if it s a code problem or your site can't handle this query.

Answer (score 0):

add below line before your query. It will solve your problem if any issue with execution timeout.

```
set_time_limit(0)
```